# React Native Context - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.theme')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I keep getting an error when I try to use Context API for dark/light mode in App.js

**Theme.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext();
//theme = light, dark

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark");

    const toggleTheme = () => {
        if (theme === "light") setTheme("dark");
        else setTheme("light");
    };

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
            {children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

App.js

```js
import { ThemeContext, ThemeProvider } from "./app/utility/ThemeManager";

export default function App() {

    const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext); // This is throwing the error

return (
  <ThemeProvider>
    ...//Rest of my app 
    //How I'd like to use my theme
      <StatusBar style={theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"} />
</ThemProvider>
);
};
```

I'd like to understand why this is throwing the error and how I could fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Import ThemeProvider in index.js

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {  ThemeProvider } from "./Theme.js";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

and in App.js

```js
import {ThemeContext} from "./Theme.js"
import StatusBar from './StatusBar';
import {useContext} from 'react'

export default function App() {

    const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext); 

return (
  <>
  ..... Rest Of your Code
</>
);
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I don't have an index.js, is there another way I could use this?